# Java Script Src Tag Issue?

Tags: javascript, tags, relative-path, src

**Setup**

Basically I have a set of Javascript inclusions like this inside of my JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="/resources/javascript/core.js"></script>
```

**Problem**

However when I load this page I get an error saying:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/javascript/core.js is not found (404)
```

**Question**

- Why is the '/' relative referencing causing resources folder to be referenced inside the localhost:8080 and not localhost:8080/myapp/resources?

Comment: Why would it magically add another folder ?

Comment: @adeneo I would not expect it to magically add another folder. But why is the root context not my app main directory? Instead it is localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not specifying it. / means that you want your path to start at the root which is always localhost (considering using local server) You can either use:

```
/myapp/resources.. //and so on
```

or use ../ notation which will move you one folder upwards (less error phrone) mainly during the shifting of files from one location to another.